# How to find maximum student marks in a list using linq? and display name and marks of that student to listbox?

Tags: c#, linq

```
namespace LinqDemo
{
    public partial class txtmarks : Form
    {
        List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
        Student stu = new Student();
        public txtmarks()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**i am using 2 textbox control here one for student name and other is for 
marks and then simply add then to listbox1 control**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    stu.Name = txtname.Text;
    stu.Marks = Convert.ToInt32(txtmrks.Text);
    student.Add(stu);
    listBox1.Items.Add(stu.ToString());
    txtname.Text = "";
    txtmrks.Text = "";
    txtname.Focus();
}
```

**the functionality of btnprocess_click is not working as expected.AS i want to show the name of student with maximum marks in listbox2**

```
private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int max = 0;
    foreach (Student st in student)
    {
        if (st.Marks > max)
        {
            max = st.Marks;
        }
    }

    var srecord = from stud in student
                    where stud.Marks == max
                    orderby stud.Marks descending
                    select stud;
    listBox2.Items.Clear();

    string message = "";
    foreach (Student s in srecord)
    {
        message += s.ToString();
    }
    listBox2.Items.Add(message);

}
```

**here is my student class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdvacneProgramingAssignment
{
    class Student
    {

        private int marks;

        public int Marks
        {
            get { return marks; }
            set
            {

                if (value < 0 && value > 100)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Marks");
                }
                else
                {
                    marks = value;
                }

            }
        }
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (value == "")
                {
                    throw new Exception("please enter student name");    
                }
                else
                {
                    name = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public string ToString()
        {
            string result = "";
            result += Name + " : " + Environment.NewLine;
            result +=Marks + Environment.NewLine;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was it really so hard to format your code?

Answer (score 3):

With LINQ

```
var max = student.Max(s => s.Marks);
var studentsWithMaxMark = student.Where(s => s.Marks == max);
var names = String.Join(",", studentsWithMaxMark.Select(s => s.Name);
```

Only first student with max mark:

```
var max = student.Max(s => s.Marks);
var name = student.First(s => s.Marks == max).Name;
```

You can also use [MoreLINQ MaxBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs):

```
var name = student.MaxBy(s => s.Marks).Name;
```

---

NOTE: Consider to improve naming of variables:

- collection of students `student` => `students`
- single mark `Marks` => `Mark`

Comment: Love using MoreLINQ, really useful extensions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum mark:

```
var maxMark = student.Max(s => s.Marks);
```

List the name and marks of students who have the maximum marks:

```
var studentsHavingMaxMark = student.Where(s => s.Marks == max)
                                   .Select(x=> new{studentNameMark = x.Name + "-" + x.Mark}).ToList();
foreach (Student s in srecord)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Display list of students in the order of their marks:

```
var studentsHavingMaxMark = student.OrderByDescending(s => s.Marks)
                                   .Select(x=> new{studentNameMark = x.Name + "-" + x.Mark}).ToList();
foreach (Student s in srecord)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(s);
}
```